# Order Statistic question

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function, order-statistics

> [image]

I guess the condition should be $E[2Y_3]=\theta$ ? Am I right ?
And I appplied first
$$f_{(3)}(x)=nf(x)\binom{n-1}{3-1}F^{2}(x)(1-F(x))^{n-3}$$

But can you explain the further procedure and $F(x)$ also ??

**Give me more hints** or help me in solving this :)

Comment: A uniform distribution on $[0,\theta]$ has cdf $F(x)=\frac x \theta$ for $0 \lt x \lt \theta$

Comment: so using this F i need to find my f3 and then I calculate direct... EY3  using integration ?

Answer (score 2):

Given a sample of size $n$ and $1\le k\le n$,

$$
\mathsf{E}Y_{(k)}=t\times\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\int_0^1 u^k(1-u)^{n-k}\,du=t\times \frac{k}{n+1}.
$$

Comment: wow! amazing, but where does this come from can you please tell me ?

Comment: The second term is the expectation of the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with parameters $n+1$ and $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $z=x-\frac\theta2$. By symmetry about the origin, the expectation of $Z_{(3)}=Y_{(3)}-\frac\theta2$ must vanish.